# Install Hibernate in Netbeans 12.0 "version 238"

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

When trying to install the Hibernate plugin in Netbeans I get an error.
There is only one post that collects the same error. I have followed the prompts and it has not worked for me.
I have reinstalled Netbeans and changed the org-netbeans-libs-freemarker.jar file.
Changing from 239 to 238:
OpenIDE module specification version: 2.44.0.238
OpenIDE module implementation version: 238

Even so, I keep getting the same error:

Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.libs.freemarker to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.libs.freemarker is requested in implementation version 238. The following plugin is affected: Hibernate.

Comment: You need to provide more detail on exactly how you attempted to install the Hibernate plugin. Describe the steps in sufficient detail so that others can attempt to reproduce your problem. Without that additional information your question may be closed.

Comment: [1] Your issue has already been raised in a bug report: [NETBEANS-4468 
No dependent plugins are available at Apache NetBeans plugin portal for Hibernate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4468). [2] There is no official solution at the moment, but a very detailed workaround was posted in the comments by Debra Petta on 7/20/20 @ 03:56. [3] Please try her approach, and post an answer to your own question here if it works for you. And if it does not work then update your question with the new information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had the same issue but aftter a good search on google, found a neat solution.
Please read the solution here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4468

just follow the discussion till you get the answer.